# How to keep video play in landscape mode when full screen mode is on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am working on an app in which i am playing video from url.I am displaying that video in small window.I am playing video in landscape mode firstly.please see snapshot.[image: Image Here]

Now i have two problem

- The UI controls on video are not scaled to small size.
- When i view video in full screen mode then it automatically rotates to portrait mode.So is there any way by which i can just play it in landscape mode only when viewed in full screen only.

**code to play video**

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    CGRect movieFrame;
    movieFrame.size = self.videoView.frame.size;
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:movieFrame];
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.videoView addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.videoView bringSubviewToFront:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.videoView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
        [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.videoView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
        [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
 [self.moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: What component do you use to play the video?

Comment: check my updated question.@Larme